# Problemas ao inserir comandos no bashrc via script

Tags: bash, shell-script

Estou tentando inserir comandos no bashrc via script.

Eu rodo o comando

```
source powerpyenv.sh

# powerpyenv.sh
echo '### Added by pyenv' >> teste
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> teste
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> teste
echo 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' >> teste

cat << EOF > temp.txt
### Activate virtualenv
alias manage="python $VIRTUAL_ENV/../manage.py"
alias r="manage runserver"
alias sa='source .venv/bin/activate; PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)\e[1;34m:/\W\e[00m$ "; clear'

### Short prompt
alias pa='PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)\e[1;34m:/\W\e[00m$ "; clear'
alias p='PS1="\e[1;34m/\W\e[00m$ "; clear'

alias rm="rm -i"
EOF

cat temp.txt >> teste
rm -f temp.txt

source teste

echo "Done"
```

Joguei tudo num teste por enquanto.

Veja o resultado do teste:

```
### Added by pyenv
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
### Activate virtualenv
alias manage="python /../manage.py"
alias r="manage runserver"
alias sa='source .venv/bin/activate; PS1="("")\e[1;34m:/\W\e[00m$ "; clear'

### Short prompt
alias pa='PS1="("")\e[1;34m:/\W\e[00m$ "; clear'
alias p='PS1="\e[1;34m/\W\e[00m$ "; clear'

alias rm="rm -i"
```

Quais os problemas aqui?

1. alias manage ficou diferente. Precisa ver como inserir o $VIRTUAL_ENV literal.
2. alias sa ficou diferente. Tanto por causa do $VIRTUAL_ENV quanto por causa da crase e do basename.

Bom como arrumar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu comando `cat <<EOF` irá usar [expansão Shell](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) sempre que encontrar subprocesso -- ``, variável -- `$`, entre outros. Caso você queira inclui-los literalmente no arquivo é necessário escapá-los, por exemplo:

```
cat > temp.txt <<EOF
### Activate virtualenv
alias manage="python \$VIRTUAL_ENV/../manage.py"
...
EOF
```